# How to change folder where applications saves configs/data

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I have Windows 7 Ultimate x64 and my personal folder `X:\Users\{myusername}` is full of folders starting with `.` which are used to store some configs/data of several applications.

Some examples are:

```
.gems, .nbi, .netbeans, .RubyMine20, .ssh, .sshterm, .VirtualBox
```

Is there a way to change this globally or is it a per-app configuration? Why can't just those apps use the `AppData` folder...?

Comment: Great question. Its question I have asked myself too. Maybe I will be able to find out why.

Comment: You use Internet Explorer? Maybe 8?

Comment: @Brian I'm not sure how IE version is relevant here

Comment: I am not sure if it is. In my case it is. In my folder there is an cache folder along with 3 other data files. These files where created months ago for a java app running via IE.

Comment: I do have IE8 installed... don't know what that has to do with this. I mean, I have those programs (Netbeans, RubyMine, VirtualBox, etc) storing their config/data in my user folder root and I don't like that =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of these seem to be *nix based tools which make use of Home directory to store configs. *nix has home directory on a per-user basis, and Windows echoes the home directory to your `\Users\<user-name>`

[image]

[image]

> Is there a way to change this globally or is it a per-app configuration?

It's a per-app config, and AFAIK there's no way to change this.

Comment: Just beat me to it. I was in the process of type in my answer when you posted yours. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Brian you're welcome! Fell free to add an answer if you feel I've missed out on something

Comment: @Saythya- You were correct. Posted another answer explaining your work since comments didn't provide enough room.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that most of them are *nix based apps... I liked your explanation =)

Answer (score 2):

I have nothing new. Sathya is right on both parts. He just didn't explain it in detail. Let me explain his answer a little. It's too much for comments so I post it as a second answer...

***What causes it?*** Windows's environment variable such as: `%homepath%`.  For Windows 7 and Vista, the variable points to the user's profile root folder at - `C:\Users\<<UsersName>>`. However, when on a Windows XP system it points to `C:\Documents and Setttings\<UserName>>`. *Keep in mind the drive letter is part of the whole variable*.

Environment variable were created to improve compatibility between different OS. More about them can be found at this [Wikipedia site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

***How is it control?***    it is control by the application. For compatibility reasons, the programmer uses variables instead of hard-code paths in there code .  So, the only way you can change the location is via registry that allows you to change the path for `%homepath%`. This is **not** recommend because it could have **ill** effects on programs that has already depended on the location of the folder.

Comment: Thanks, the %homepath% var is the "problem" and yes, If I cd %homepath% it goes to my user folder. Of course I won't touch it. So I'll have to live with that =(